# What Drive account does Google Apps Script access?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Use Case:** Shared Google Sheet.  Owned by Master.  Primarily edited by me.  Viewable by anyone with a link.  Users use a Google Form to add data which is displayed on a main sheet.  Then I use Jaws to take a snapshot of the main sheet and email it to a group, along with the form response.  When we set this up, it was under Master's account and everything worked fine.  I ran the script from my account today (requiring authorization step) and now all of the png's are stored to my Google Drive instead of Master's.  I either need to revert back to storing them in Master's (ideal) or figure out how to tell the GAS to look at my drive instead of Master's.  Any thoughts?

```
function onSubmit(e) {
  sheetCapture();
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('newimage.png');  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: 'me@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Current Sheet Image',
    body: e.values[1].toString() + ', ' + e.values[2].toString() + ', ' + e.values[3].toString(),
    attachments: [files.next()]
  });
  // files.next().setTrashed(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: If I understand, you're saving the snapshot on the the root folder of Google Drive of the account running the script. If you don't want that, Master can create a folder and your script can always store the files in that specific folder owned by Master.

Answer (score 0):

What I eventually found is that I set up the onSubmit project trigger under one Google account and I had to set it up in the other instead.  Whichever account is running the trigger, that's where files get stored.